# grep not counting characters accurately when they are clearly in file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to count the number of times '(' appears in a file. I get a number back but it's never accurate.

Why won't grep accuratly count the occurences of this character. It must be multiline and every occurrences.

I imagine my regex is off, but it's so simple.

log.txt:

```
(eRxîó¬Pä^oË'AqŠêêÏ-04ây9Í&ñ­ÖbèaïÄ®h0FºßôÊ$&Ð>0dÏ“ ²ˆde^áä­ÖÚƒíZÝ*ö¨tM
variable        1
paren )
(¼uC¼óµr\=Œ"J§ò<ƒu³ÓùËP
<åÐ#ô{ô
½ÊªÆÏglTµ¥>¦³éùoÏWÛz·ób(ÈIH|TT]
variable        0
paren )
```

Output:

```
$ grep -o "(" log.txt | wc -l

1
```

**EDIT:**

I had a wierd mix of encoding so I dump it then count the hex values.

```
hexdump -C hex.txt | grep "28" | wc -l
```

Comment: That's the right answer, but not what I'm getting.

Comment: What you have will output the number of lines containing "(", not the number of "("

Comment: try `grep -c "(" log.txt` instead

Comment: @ReubenL. I took the text and saved it into a different file, and then it worked. I'm wondering if the file format has anything to do with it.

Comment: probably encoding issue then

Comment: @Reuben - if you omit the `-o` flag, then `grep` won't give you a line of output for each _match_ - you'll get a line of output for each _line containing matches_.  Not the same thing if you have more than one match in a line.

Answer (score 1):

You might have encoding issues, if you interpret a single-byte encoding in a multibyte locale.  Here's an approach that deletes everything except `(` (in a single-byte locale), then counts the remaining characters:

```
LC_ALL=C <log.txt tr -c -d '(' | wc -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Dump the unknown encoding and count hex values.

```
hexdump -C hex.txt | grep "28" | wc -l
```

Comment: That will count only lines (blocks) containing 28 (including literal '28' in the line address or the ASCII representation).

Answer (score 0):

using sed (than counting with wc because only in sed it's a bit heavy for that)

```
sed -e '1h;1!h;$!d' -e 'x;s/[^(]//g' yourfile | wc -c
```

using awk

```
awk -F '(' '{ Total += NF - 1 } END { print Total }' YourFile
```